# Tomcat startup: Reporting success even if web application failed to deploy

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

I'm developing a web service using:

- Tomcat 7.0.57
- [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework) MVC 4.1.6
- Linux Fedora 20

I deploy my web application by copying it as an expanded folder as the ROOT context folder. Everything works fine, **but when the web application fails to deploy** during Spring initialization for whatever reason (for example, connecting to a cache service at startup), **Tomcat still report successful startup** messages:

```
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/webapps/myapp/webapps/ROOT has finished in 20,547 ms
INFO: Server startup in 20591 ms
```

In the same logs I can see previously the exception stack trace so I realize this is failing:

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jul 20, 2015 9:22:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'createTokenResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: 
....
Jul 20, 2015 9:22:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Then I wonder why Tomcat reports that both as deployment error and success. I've been taking a look at the implementation of Catalina `HostConfig#deployDirectory` and it seems to 'silently swallow' the exception.

1. Is this the intended behaviour of Tomcat?
2. Is there some deployment mode which I can force a Tomcat startup error if my ROOT application fails to deploy?
3. Is this changed/work-arounded in some other version of Tomcat?
4. Am I taking a bad deployment approach?
5. Am I focusing wrong the whole thing?

You can assume that this web application will be the only application running in my Tomcat server.

Comment: Tomcat is started successfully and not the application...Its something like that let us suppose some instance of Tomcat is running ,now you deploy your project on that running tomcat instance ..Now even your project fail to deploy even then tomcat will run.

Comment: Yes, I know it Subodh Joshi. Please read #2 question.

Comment: THink about that: If you deploy two apps, one can deploy correctly and the other one could fail. Anyway tomcat starts succesfully and you can access the app that was deployed correctly

Comment: Thats the intended behaviour, but you can embedd Tomcat into your application to have full controll.

Comment: OK Fran, Stefan. So my best option is to embed Tomcat. I was thinking of doing that with Spring Boot.